# How to load a Pixijs BitmapText in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, webpack, pixi.js

I have been banging my head on the wall for some hours now. I am having a hard time loading a .fnt file into pixijs. Here's the process I have been through.

1. Using bitmap Font generator for windows I've exported a .fnt file in XML format.
2. Adding the .fnt to the loader

```
     const loader = new PIXI.Loader()
            loader.add("fnt", require('../../assets/sprites/arial.fnt'));
            loader.load(function() {
                const bitmapFontText = new PIXI.BitmapText('BITMAP FONTS', { font: '24px Arial' });
                bitmapFontText.anchor.set(0.5)
                bitmapFontText.position.x = 50
                bitmapFontText.position.y = 50
                this.viewport.addChild(bitmapFontText);
            });
```

I then add the error :

> Module parse failed: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Which I think I solved this way inside my webpack.config using File-Loader

```
       module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.fnt$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'file-loader',
                            options: {
                                name: '[./src/assets/sprites][name].[ext]',
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        }
```

3. Creating `PIXI.BitmapText`

It seems my font is still not fully loaded because I get this error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined

What am I missing

PS: I made sure I was using the `Face` attribute from the arial.fnt file in `{ font: '24px Arial' }`

Comment: Have you read this thread https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/5199? I think it would help you. It seem your code right now only load `fnt` file not `png` file.

Comment: Thanks I read it but still not sure how to implement it. Thing is, PNG have always loaded correctly so far.

Comment: So, there is a request to that PNG on Network Tab? Could you share the error stack of `Cannot read property 'size' of undefined`?